# WCF RESTful Service Error

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

Hi I came accross this error and cant figure out exactly how to fix it. I have a RESTful WCF service trying to retrieve data from a SQL Server Database. Thanks.

```
Error   1   'RestService.RestServiceImpl.GetCompany(string)': not all code paths return a value
```

My coding

RestServiceImpl.svc.cs

```
    public class RestServiceImpl : IRestServiceImpl
    {
        public string XMLDATA(string id)
        {
            return ("You Requested product" + id);
        }
        public string JSONDATA(string id)
        {
            return ("You Requested product" + id);
        }        //ERROR underlined at GetCompany 
        public Company GetCompany(string CompID)
        {
            Company comp = new Company();
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "";
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COMPANYNAME FROM tblCompany", con);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

IRestService.cs

```
  public interface IRestServiceImpl
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "xml/{id}")]
        string XMLDATA(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONDATA(string id);

        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetCompany/{CompID}",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        Company GetCompany(string CompID);

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Company
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string CompID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your method to return the type of object 'Company'

```
 public Company GetCompany(string COMPANYNAME)
        {
            Company comp = new Company();
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                con.ConnectionString = "";
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COMPANYNAME FROM tblCompany", con);
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //Your implementation
            }
            return comp ;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return as per your method which requires the object of class `Company`:-

```
 public Company GetCompany(string COMPANYNAME)
            {
                Company comp = new Company();
                {
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
                    con.ConnectionString = "";
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COMPANYNAME FROM tblCompany", con);
                    con.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                }

               return comp;

            }
```